# Are there any standardized questionnaires available for asking adults about their opinion on the suitability of a system designed for children?

Tags: usability, questionnaire, children

My team and I have developed an augmented reality app for children (primary school students).

I would like to get their teachers' opinions about the usability of the system in the context of their students.

First, I thought about using standardized questionnaires like System Usability Scale or User Experience Questionnaire but those are designed for asking the actual user of a system and furthermore, I actually don't want too much focus on the usability rather than on their opinion about the suitability of the system for children.

I am wondering if there are any standardized questionnaires available for cases like that.